# Unexpected result in jSoup select() with ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, jsoup, railo, cfml

For some reason, I am always getting an odd result from my `select()` calls to the jSoup object.

Here is my code (I am trying to get simple title and meta tag values and insert them into my object called 'request'):

```
<cfset jsoupObject = createObject("component","lib.javaloader.JavaLoader").init([ expandPath('/lib/jsoup-1.7.2.jar') ]) />
<cfset jsoupCreate = jsoupObject.create("org.jsoup.Jsoup") />           
<cfset parsed = jsoupCreate.parse(document.filecontent) />

<cfset variables.request = {} />
<cfset variables.request.title = parsed.select("title").first() />
<cfset variables.request.description = parsed.select("meta[name=description]").first() />
```

Because I have this in a CFC, I am using a Java Loader, which works fine. `document.filecontent` is a block of HTML code, which works fine.

When I output my request object I get the following results:

[image]

What could be going wrong here?

You can ignore the other keys in the request object, the only ones to note here are **description** and **title**, which both give me weird results!

I am loading my HTML via `CFHTTP` in some code prior to this (all works fine).

I'd really appreciate your help.

Many thanks,
Michael.

**UPDATE:**

Dumping 'parsed' I get the following:

[image]

Dumping `parsed.select("title")` I get:

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you dump "parsed"? Also if you dump the result of the select without doing "first" on it?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the quick reply. See my edit's above with further screenshots. I am using Railo. jSoup has worked fine in the past, so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: Hmm.. It looks like the result of select is being processed as an array, rather than an "Elements" like in Java JSoup. Does it work if you do select(...)[1] instead of .first()?

Comment: @Marcin Doing select('title')[1] yields the same result as select('title').first()

Comment: Weird, from the dump of parsed.select it's clearly an array of Element - don't see why it's changing (but I also use ACF not Railo, so it might be some Railo quirk?)

What if you try getting the text instead of dumping the element? eg. `parsed.select('title').first().text()`?

Comment: Okay, THAT works...I'm a bloody idiot. Of course, I was storing the object / match and was expecting the text...I forgot about having to do that. Oh my word. Place that as an answer and I'll mark you as correct! Thanks so much for your speedy help :)

Comment: @Marcin Okay, THAT works...I'm a bloody idiot. Of course, I was storing the object / match and was expecting the text...I forgot about having to do that. Oh my word. Place that as an answer and I'll mark you as correct! Thanks so much for your speedy help :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29591/discussion-between-marcin-and-michael-giovanni-pumo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're storing the actual Element rather than the content of the tag, which is what I assume you were intending. Even though you'd expect it to dump as a Java object there might be some quirk that's stopping that.  You probably want to store the actual text instead of dumping the element though, eg:

```
<cfset variables.request.title = parsed.select("title").first().text() />
```